How to specialize the return type of a method in Kotlin
I want to implement a specific persistence in Kotlin, where I need to wrap the object to be persisted; yet, I still want to access some part of the persisted (generic) object in a type-safe way. How can I constrain the return type in the following?
sealed interface State

enum class StateA : State { A1, A2 } // example state implementation
enum class StateB : State { B1, B2 }

interface StatefulEntity {
    val state: State
}

// as example; real entities have different additional fields
data class EntityA(override val state: StateA, val ...) : StatefulEntity
data class EntityB(override val state: StateB, val ...) : StatefulEntity

// Wrap the entity for persistence but provide access to the state
data class EntityContainer<E: StatefulEntity>(
    private val entity: E,
    private val referenceId: String // Some metadata to affix to the entity
) {
    val state: State // Should be StateA or StateB, depending on E
        get() = entity.state

    // Same here, should also work on the concrete state type implied by E
    fun updateState(state: State): EntityContainer<E: StatefulEntity> { .. }
}

Key point here is that while the EntityContainer is generic, once I select a specific type parameter for the contained entity, the type of the state field of this specific subtype of StatefulEntity is known. So it should be possible for the state getter function to provide this specific type instead of just the supertype State. I am looking for some hypothetical construct like val state: E::state to refer to the type of the field state of the constrained type parameter E.
Is there a way to achieve this without introducing an additional type parameter; i.e.,
interface StatefulEntity<S: State> { val state: S }

data class EntityContainer<E: StatefulEntity<S>, S: State>(...) {
   ...
   val state: S
   fun updateState(state: S) ...
}

This latter solutions seems to be verbose and creates problems in other places. It is as if I would need to explicitly tell the compiler something it already knows – the type of the state field in a concrete StatefulEntity.

What if the StatefulEntity instance doesn't pick a concrete type for state? What should the type be then?

I should be whatever type is used in the concrete argument passed to the type parameter E

I believe your last sample is the way to go. Both Kotlin and Java don't support "extracting" the type parameter from another type parameter. All type params have to be declared explicitly. And yes, I sometimes miss this feature too.

"It is as if I would need to explicitly tell the compiler something it already knows"
It might feel that way, but it's really about scope. If you have an instance of EntityContainer<EntityA>, then the compiler knows, for that specific instance, that the generic type is EntityA an therefore the state is StateA.
The problem is that within the EntityContainer class, there is no way to know E beyond that it is some StatefulEntity. It's impossible to write a function from within the EntityContainer class which changes the return type of the State without your generic solution.

@Josh Is there any technical reason it cannot be done? Your explanation sounds like: "It can't be done, because it is not possible". I personally don't see a reason it cannot be supported by Kotlin, it just isn't as of 1.9.x.

@broot You're basically right. If the type of State is not generic, I'm not sure how you'd specify the type of the exposing state property in EntityContainer. There's just no mechanism for that at the moment

I guess there is a big difference between compile time and runtime. At runtime, all generic type parameters are lost because of type erasure. But at compile time, type parameters are propagated and thus should be available for type inference.
